# Item not found in this collection

Tags: vba

I got an "item not found in this collection" error
Here is my code:

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("prodTest")


Dim myName As String
Dim myDate As Date
Dim myType As String
Dim myShift As String
Dim mySupervisor As String

myName = Me.Combo0
myDate = Me.Combo7
myType = Me.Combo10
myShift = Me.Combo14
mySupervisor = Me.Combo18


rs.AddNew
    rs("TYPE OF WORK").Value = myType
    rs("EMPLOYEE NAME").Value = myName
   rs("DATE").Value = myDate
    rs("SHIFT").Value = myShift
    rs("SHIFT SUPERVISOR").Value = mySupervisor

rs.Update
```

what I can make the insert to a test table with these fields but when I was trying to insert  the linked table that I imported from "Get external data", it will show this error, I dont know what's wrong...

Comment: Are you sure the field names are correct? `EDIT`: Also you actually have those comboboxes? Which line is giving you the error? Also Are you doing this in MS-ACCESS VBA?

Answer (score 0):

Please try something like the code below (on both "production" and "test" tables) in order to check the fields :

```
Dim iI as Integer

For iI = 0 To (rs.Fields.Count - 1)
    Debug.Print rs.Fields(iI).Name
Next
```

or concatenate the names to a string and `MsgBox` it, or whatever suits you best.

PS : I'm not a big fan of your combobox control names, but nevermind...

Comment: `PS : I'm not a big fan of your combobox control names, but nevermind...` That is because I guess the user is using MS-ACCESS where the comboboxes are named by default in that way :)